# Adding elements of a 1D array to an Image?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

import numpy as np
import random
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('baboon.png')

I = np.array(im) #2D array of 512 by 512

data = np.random.randint(2, size=131072) #1D array

I have a 512 x 512 image and I want to add the elements of data which are a 1 or a 0 for 132072 times randomly in the 512 x 512 image. How can this be done to form a new image with the original image + the added data elements?

Comment: So you want to add the random numbers to the values of the image? Like either add a 1 or 0 to each element?

Comment: yes that's what I want to form a new image with those added numbers

Comment: Why is the size of the **data** array 131072?

Comment: it doesn't really matter but when the size is 131072, it means that I am adding the data to half of the pixels in the baboon image. As the baboon image has 512x512 pixels = 262144 pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well the general result is going to be a slightly more noisy picture. Here is some sample code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = Image.open('baboon.png')

l = np.array(im)

data = 50*np.random.randint(2, size=(512,512,3))

l_new = (l+data).astype(np.uint8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].imshow(l)
ax[1].imshow(l_new)
fig.show()
```

Which will give:
[image]

In this case we had to use a 512x512x3 sized array because the image has 3 colour channels (R,G,B). Also note that I multiplied the **data** array by 50, because each colour channel was 8 bit (i.e. values go from 0 to 255), and so adding 1 will not result in much of a visible difference, while adding 50 will.

Does this help?

## Edit:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load image, convert to greyscale
im = Image.open('baboon.png').convert('L')

l = np.array(im)

data = np.random.randint(2, size=131072)

# To add we need to pad data so it contains the same number of elements
padSize = (l.shape[0]*l.shape[1])-data.shape[0]
data_new = np.pad(data, (0,padSize), mode='constant')

# Now we reshape data
data_reshaped = data_new.reshape((512,512))

l_new = l+data_reshaped

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].imshow(l, cmap=plt.cm.Greys)
ax[1].imshow(l_new,cmap=plt.cm.Greys)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The thing is the data vector is requested to be a unmodified 1d vector as I listed and then I am somehow required to store the indices of the elements of the data vector to then add them to the same location in the baboon image. And the baboon image can be changed to grayscae before adding the data elements. The only thing that can change is the length of the data vector.

Comment: Okay see the new edit. You can't really see any difference though for the reason I wrote before.

Comment: Could you actually store the indices of the elements of the data vector by using random sample and then add the data elements in the same indices of the babbon image?

Comment: Not really because how would you decide which indices are corresponding? Since they are different shapes and sizes there's no unique was to specify which image pixel corresponds to each value in the 1D array

Comment: Using a seed. I need to generate a seed and with the seed I create the list of locations where I will add the data elements to the image.

Comment: Huh? A seed is just an initial value for a pseudorandom number generator. What I am asking is this: when you have your **data** vector, how do you decide how to add it to the **l** array? They are not the same size or shape so there is no way to do this, unless you *pad* out the values or similar.

Comment: I am basically trying to implement an algorithm called LSB embedding. yi = xi - (xi mod 2) + di; where yi is the new formed image and xi is the baboon image and di are the elements of the data vector.

Comment: I need the seed as later on I will have to extract the added data vector from the new formed image.

Comment: Okay well you can set a seed using **np.random.seed**, as for LSB embedding, check out https://grocid.net/2014/10/04/steganography-with-python/

Comment: My issue was is you rightly pointed out the adding of the two by using the resulting random indices  which will indicate the location position that will be added to the cover image.

Comment: Well you can just pad the data out (as I did), can't you?

Comment: Yeah I could but the way you added the data in the baboon image is not random. You added the data to image in a sequential manner.

Comment: Okay no problem, have a go at LSB embedding and if you get stuck post another question (remember the guidelines though!)